# PDO result to PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I'm really stuck here... :/
Here is my problem, I need to get at PDO result to a PHP array. Something like this:

```
- Database - 
John
Peter
James
```

This I need to get into a PHP array and to look like this:

```
$names = array('John', 'Peter', 'James')
```

How is this done, and how do I remove the last comma to make it work?
(I have tried dusins of ideas, and no luck at all).

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db",$username,$password);
$conn->query('SET NAMES UTF8');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_name"; 
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($title));
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
while($data = $q->fetch()){ ????? (what to put here???) }
```

Comment: Can you add your PDO query code? And have you read the [PDOStatemen fetchAllt](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) documentation?

Comment: Sure, I use my regular PDO query:

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db",$username,$password);
$conn->query('SET NAMES UTF8');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_name";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($title));
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
while($data = $q->fetch()){
????? (what to put here???)
}

And yes, I have even tried with the "FetchAll" statement.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways. Assuming the column containing the names is named `name`,
we can use the loop like this:

```
$names = array();
while($data = $q->fetch())
  $names[] = $data['name'];
```

or you could fetch a single column as an array like this:

```
$names = $q->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 'name' );
```

*UPDATE*

As requested, here's a complete example, including a demonstration of using query parameters in PDO. Here, we select all entries from `tbl_name` where the `title` column starts with `$title`, and print a list with the `name` column:

```
$db = new PDO( "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $username, $password, array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND  => "SET NAMES utf8",
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
) );

$sth = $db->prepare( "
    SELECT *
    FROM tbl_name 
    WHERE title LIKE ?
" );
$sth->execute( array( "$title%" ) );

// put the names in an array
$names = [];
while( $row = $sth->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) )
    $names[] = $row['name'];
```

Note, that is more efficient to only select the columns you need: `SELECT name FROM tbl_name`.

Comment: Could you tell how to put this in the PDO query and echo it? Still kinda a PHP noob... :/

Comment: Not sure I follow - I did update your question with the code you added in your comment, and that code is fine. You can use either of the two snippets in my answer instead of your `while` line. How do you want to echo it? You could add `foreach ( $names as $name ) { echo "<div>$name</div>"; }` for instance.

Comment: As the PHP noob I am, I have no idea how to work with your answer. It's like half pointers, go figure out the rest... I need it dumbed down I'm affraid.

Comment: Ok I added a complete example. Hope that clarifies things?

Comment: Much better, thanks :)

But I need the result to be like this: 'John', 'Peter', 'James'  -so that I can put it in a array.

Comment: Changed the last loop to put the names into an array. There's no need to first create a comma separated string first (like `$nameString = implode(', ', $names);`) only to create an array out of it again ( `$names = array_map( 'trim', explode(',', $nameString))`).